# select data from multiple tales using linq query

Tags: linq

I have 2 tables I want to select all records from table one but in second table i want select all records that's on the id base that id is not related to table one  .i want to do this in linq query .
any help

Comment: Please provide sample input and output. It's hard to understand what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

For what I could understand, you want to do a join between the two tables:

```
var query = database.FirstTable                                                             // starting point - the first table from your question
                    .Join(database.SecondTable,                                             // the second table
                              first => first.ID,                                            // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
                              second => second.first_ID,                                    // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
                              (first, second) => new { First = first, Second = second })    // selection
                    .Where(result => result.first.ID == id);                                // where statement
```